# MVC MiniProfiler with ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler, asp.net-mvc-4

After adding MVC MiniProfiler to my ASP.NET MVC 4 project, it complains about requiring `System.Web.Mvc 3.0.0.0`.

Is there any way to use MiniProfiler with ASP.NET MVC 4?

The following assembly redirect is already defined in `web.config`:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: I managed to get this scenario working. I am using a similar binding redirect directive. Did you solve this in the end?

Comment: I got it working, but I can't remember what I did.

Answer (score 2):

I just created a new asp.net mvc 4 project and used nuget to grab the latest miniprofiler package.  It started up just fine.  Have you tried this?  If you are using nuget, perhaps you should try to remove the mini profiler and then test, then add it back.

On difference in my project however is that my `assemblyIdentity` line includes a culture:

```
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
```

Answer (score 1):

What setting do you have for `MvcBuildViews` in your project file? If your build error message is whingeing about a view try setting `MvcBuildViews` to false to get you through the compilation stage, then the binding redirect to MVC 4 should likely work as expected at run time.

BTW, to edit the `MvcBuildViews` setting you'll have to unload the project and edit the .proj file direct, you can't change this setting via the project settings screen in VS.

Comment: This is a compile-time error, so the binding redirect does not help, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an assembly binding redirect for `System.Web.Mvc`?